# Padding std::vector<uint8_t> in embedded c++

Tags: c++, embedded

I am a newbie in c++ and I have a problem with https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils:

In that source I see `isotpsend` with option `-p` is padding data

ex: my data is

```
std::vector<uint8_t> Data = {34,00,24,FD,C0,7E,2E,20,00}
```

I use command

```
echo 34 00 24 FD C0 7E 2E 20 00 | isotpsend -s 068 -d 069 -p 0:0 can0
```

This is result

```
can0  068   [8]  10 09 34 00 24 FD C0 7E
can0  069   [8]  30 08 14 00 94 96 C0 FD
can0  068   [8]  21 2E 20 00 00 00 00 00
can0  069   [8]  06 74 40 00 00 0F FF 00
```

68 is id send, 69 is id resopne

Like you see this line 3

```
can0  068   [8]  21 2E 20 00 00 00 00 00
```

can0  068   [8]  21 2E 20 00 **00 00 00 00**
-> 4 bytes is padded in my data

How to do this? Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you asking how they add the padding bytes?

Comment: Is there a reason you use std::vector instead of std::array? Seems the length is known at compile time so I do not see the need for dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: `Data.resize(Data.size() + 4)` will add four bytes with value zero at the end of `Data`. If that's what you  are asking.

Comment: That said, the command you cite appears to add some bytes at the beginning of each packet that weren't part of the original data: `10 09` on the first line, `21` on the third line. I assume that's part of the communication protocol, which I suppose you are expected to implement. Padding with trailing zeros is probably the least of your difficulties.

Comment: @ALL Thank you reply ```Data.resize(Data.size() + 4)``` this will add data to my Data it is not correct, I want to add data padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for supported,
Answer is linux kernel will auto add data padding, I will set it in `setsockopt`